# Is the difficulty truly dynamic in Resident Evil 2 Remake?

Tags: resident-evil-2-2019

I've seen two styles of difficulty adjustment referenced for the RE 2 remake:

1. Dynamic: Depending on how well you are / are not doing the game will, behind the scenes, adjust the difficulty of the game. Apparently it can change the health levels of zombies, the strength of bullets, and so forth.
2. Allowing the player to select difficulty: We have probably all seen this, if you die enough times you get the option to change the difficulty mode.

Is option 1, the dynamic variant, actually occurring in the background? And if so, what are the factors and effects of the dynamic difficulty?

Answer (score 2):

Based on how often you die you can either :

- advance throughout the game without dying and the game becomes harder : more enemies and less ammo
- die quite frequently and with each death the number of zombies decrease and the ammo can be found more easily

This has been also tested by GameRevolution in this article:

https://www.gamerevolution.com/guides/491409-resident-evil-2-adaptive-difficulty-zombies-ammo#/slide/1

Comment: +1 This is a great read - but did they actually test it? It still feels like heresay (I've read a few articles that claim the same thing)

Comment: From what I could see playing the game, it feels like when you are in a tight spot or a bad day (being distracted) the zombies that appeared in the past becomes corpses on another try. So I agree with them.

Comment: I don't disagree (I noticed the same) - just looking for concrete stats/evidence. Digging deeper, this thread seems interesting: https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/179835-resident-evil-2/77488226/917570778

Comment: It is also noteworthy that previous installments of the Resident Evil franchise have used dynamic difficulty in the form of your "first" definition. This goes back to [at least Resident Evil 4](https://www.engadget.com/2015/06/03/resident-evil-4-difficulty/). Be sure to come back to this post and accept Softability's answer.